# Problem with configuring the farm

Tags: 2010, server-farm, configuration-wizard, service-account, farm-setup

i have a sharepoint server, when it comes to configuring the farm, sharepoint does not accept my account for the Database Access Account, i get "The username is invalid. The account must be a valid domain account." The problem is that the account is valid. I tried

1. Made sure that the account is valid by adding it and accessing the server in remote using the account.
2. Made sure the account is not over 15 characters with the domain name.
3. Installing sharepoint, removing and adding back the computer before the farm configuration process.

I tried to add the account to SQL but without success, is it why this isnt working ?

Thanks alot :)

Comment: Is the account in the form of ADDomain\User or MachineName\User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it ! I had to login in as the user i wanted to add.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [accountname]@[FQDN] in the wizard.